# How to change space between y-axis and first bar in a stacked barchart

Tags: output-formatting, charts

I have a stacked barchart like this one:

```
BarChart[{{1, 3, 5}, {4, 7, 9}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

Is there a way to change the space before and after the bars (eg. make it smaller)? As far as I know with `BarSpacing` you can only change the space between the bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `PlotRange`, e.g.

```
BarChart[{{1, 3, 5}, {4, 7, 9}},
 Frame -> True,
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 2.5}, All},
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, Automatic}}]
```

Note that I set `PlotRangePadding` to zero to make it easier to see the plot range changes.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow thanks so easy. I was not expecting that. So i just missed `PlotRange`